# Ignore already imported records on CSV import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, csv

I've got a simple thing going for manually importing CSV files of transaction data on a daily basis and putting them into a SQLite DB.

In the case of importing a file containing previously imported records, I'd like to ignore importing those records. How do I best achieve this? (I've got a field called 'aka_reference' that in theory should be unique.)

Model:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            Transaction.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `aka_reference` is an attribute in Transaction then it's easy...

```
Transaction.create!(row.to_hash) unless Transaction.find_by(aka_reference:  row.to_hash['aka_reference'])
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two possibility. Either you can use `find_or_create_by` method. something like this

```
 class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            Transaction.find_or_create_by row.to_hash
        end
    end
end
```

And the other case if to use `aka_reference` field. Something like this

```
 class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            data = row.to_hash
            Transaction.create!(data) unless Transaction.exists?(aka_reference: data[:aka_reference])           
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: thx, prefer the semantics of your Transaction.find_or_create_by solution, but couldn't actually get it to work (i.e. on importing same CSV x2, amount of records also double)